# Вопрос про MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, шаблоны-проектирования, mvvm

Хочу переделать свой UserControl в стиле MVVM, но у меня получается так, что ViewModel должна знать о View и управлять её внешним видом (например изменять Width Canvas.Top и т.д.).

Но я как понимаю ViewModel ничего не должна знать и уж тем более менять внешнее поведение View.

Comment: Начальство требует чтоб я переделал UserControl в стиле MVVM.
Сам котрол меняет своё состояние по событиям Thumb.DragDelta
В событие Thumb.DragDelta происходит изменение View (Width/Canvas.Top).
Я не понимаю где это событие должно обрабатываться в самой View или ViewModel.
Если в View, то зачем тогда вообще ViewModel нужна, что там должно содержаться.
Мож я пытаюсь засунуть MVVM туда где он не нужен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, почему он это должен делать. ViewModel выставляет наружу public свойства, на которые может делать биндинг View. Если внешний вид каким-то образом зависит от состояния ViewModel, то лучше на уровне View эту логику писать. В этом очень помогают конвертеры (IValueConverter) и триггеры.

Если что-то более конкретное скажете о задаче, то, возможно, помочь будет легче